# Display Selected Drop Down List Item In Angular 4

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am struck in a situation where I have to display the below 4 details in a row (repeated) 
1. Country Name (Drop Down List)
2. Date Format (Read Only)
3. Mobile Format (Read Only)
4. UniqueID Format (Read Only)

Consider there are 10 countries, and user has selected 3 countries then 3 rows should be displayed. But however the CountryName field is a drop down list which contains the list of all 10 countries. When he changes the country from the drop down then the other properties should get changed.

I am to show the read only properties from the model data but unfortunately I am not able to bind the selected country name to the rows.

Below is the code snippet

```
            <div class="col-md-9 activationSelect">
                <div class="row" *ngFor="let country of countryList">
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <mat-form-field>
                            <mat-select formControlName="CountryName">
                                <mat-option value="{{country.id}}" selected>
                                    {{country.countryName}}
                                </mat-option>                
                            </mat-select>
                        </mat-form-field>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-3 mt7">
                        <mat-form-field>
                          <input matInput formControlName="DateFormat" value="{{country.dateFormat}}" readonly >                                
                        </mat-form-field>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-3 mt7">
                        <mat-form-field>
                          <input matInput formControlName="MobileFormat" value="{{country.mobileFormat}}" readonly>                                
                        </mat-form-field>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-3 mt7">
                        <mat-form-field>
                          <input matInput formControlName="UniqueIdType" value="{{country.uniqueIdType}}" readonly>                                
                        </mat-form-field>
                    </div>

                </div>

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-3 mt15">
                        <label (click)="addCountry()" class="cursor-pointer font-capitalize text-rose font500 font12">+ Add Country</label>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

export interface ICountry {
    id: number,
    countryName: string,
    dateFormat: string,
    mobileFormat: string,
    uniqueIdType: string,
    uniqueIdFormat: string,
    countryCode: string
}

Answer (score 0):

Use ngForm. Import it your component.module.ts(module file)

```
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
```

Add it your component template

```
<form role="form" (ngSubmit)="f.form.valid && onSubmit()" #f="ngForm" novalidate>
    <select name="name_id" [(ngModel)]="model.name_id" #name_id="ngModel" [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': f.submitted && name_id.invalid }" required>
        <option value="" disabled selected>Select Name</option>
        <option *ngFor="let name of allnames" [value]="name.name_id">{{name.name}}</option>
    </select>
    <div *ngIf="f.submitted && name_id.invalid" class="invalid-feedback">
        <div *ngIf="name_id.errors.required">Name is required</div>
    </div>
    <button type="submit">save</button>
</form>
```

Add it your component.ts

```
allnames = [{
    name_id: 1,
    name: 'Jhon'
}, {
    name_id: 2,
    name: 'Chena'
}, {
    name_id: 3,
    name: 'Jack'
}]
model: any = {};
ngOnInit() {
    this.model.name_id = 2;
}
```

The name `Chena` is selected. It's work well. And i will use it.

Comment: This seems to be not apt for my scenario.

Comment: You want display Selected drop down list item. Use select box **ngmodel**